# message collector_discord.js v12

Tags: discord.js

```js
if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'say'){
    let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
    let q1 = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, filter, {
        max: 1
    })
    message.channel.send('ما هي القناة التي ترغب بارسال الرسالة اليها ؟');

    q1.on('collect', async (message, col) => {
        let channel = message.mentions.channels.first();

        message.channel.send('ما هي رسالتك ؟')
        q1.stop();
        let q2 = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, filter, {
            max: 1
        })
        q2.on('collect', async (message, col) => {
            channel.send(message.content);
            message.delete();
            args.shift();
            message.channel.send("تم الارسال");
            q2.stop();
        })
    })


}
```

i have this message collector for discord.js v12 but when i change my prefix with a command to use a custom prefix the "say" command does not work

Comment: What are you changing your prefix to? What system are you using to change your prefix?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your `if` statement - `if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'say'){ ... }` will *only* execute if the message you've sent is exactly "say". To make it work, you could do something like this:

```
const prefix = "PREFIX";
if(message.content.toLowerCase() === `${prefix}say`) { ... }
```

Make sure you also check the guide, starting with this: https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/configuration-files.html#implementing-your-config-file